# problems with ifthen and tabularx

Tags: tables, conditionals

I have a problem related with ifthen and tabularx packages.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx,colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\def\kw{2}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Title}
        \include{file}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

if the included file is:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|X|}
    \hline
    Bla & Blabla\\
    \hline
    \hline
    1 & something \\
    %\ifthenelse{\equal{\kw}{2}}{\rowcolor{red}}{}
    \rowcolor{red}
    \hline      
    2 & something else\\
    \hline
    3 & something else\\
    \hline      
\end{tabularx}
```

I get the desired output:

[image: desired output]

However, if I change the 'file' to (note commented parts)

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|X|}
    \hline
    Bla & Blabla\\
    \hline
    \hline
    1 & something \\
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\kw}{2}}{\rowcolor{red}}{}
    %\rowcolor{red}
    \hline      
    2 & something else\\
    \hline
    3 & something else\\
    \hline      
\end{tabularx}
```

I get a bunch of errors ("Misplaced \noalign \end{tabularx}" etc) and this output:

[image: faulty output]

I am thankful for any clues...

Edit: if I use \input instead of \include the problem remains the same.

Comment: you can not use `\ifthenelse` in such a position `\rowcolor` like `\multicolumn` has to be the first thing in the cell.

Comment: Ok, so the whole "ifthenelse" expression is not replaced by its value? Because then  \rowcolor would indeed be the first thing in that cell...

Comment: You shouldn't use `\include`, to begin with

Comment: @egreg: I changed \include to \input but the problem remains the same

Comment: @D.F.F not early enough it does some tests and assignments internally so it is like `{\def\zzzz{}}\rowcolor`  which would give the same error

Comment: @D.F.F The usage of `\input` versus `\include` has no influence on the issue; it's just “best practice”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `\include` should be `\input`, but it's not the problem.

The issue is that `\rowcolor` must be the first item in a row, after expansion, so you need to use an expandable test, which `\ifthenelse` isn't. With `etoolbox` it's easy.

By the way, `beamer` already loads `xcolor`, so in order to load `colortbl` it's best to pass it the `table` option, which is done by adding `xcolor=table` to the global options.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\def\kw{2}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|X|}
  \hline
  Bla & Blabla\\
  \hline
  \hline
  1 & something \\
  \ifnumcomp{\kw}{=}{2}{\rowcolor{red}}{}
  \hline
  2 & something else\\
  \hline
  3 & something else\\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx,colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\def\kw{2}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Title}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|X|}
    \hline
    Bla & Blabla\\
    \hline
    \hline
    1 & something\ifthenelse{\equal{\kw}{2}}{\\\rowcolor{red}}{\\}%
    \hline      
    2 & something else\\
    \hline
    3 & something else\\
    \hline      
\end{tabularx}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That works. Thx!

Comment: @D.F.F The point is that `\ifthen` isn't a so-called "expandable" conditional, which disappears without a trace after having done its job, so to speak. Tabular parsing in TeX sometimes needs such vanishing beasts at the start of cell. However if we let it expand at the end of the last cell of the previous row, it's ok.